# How to get all values for the same key from key-value pairs in python dictionary

Tags: python

How to iterate over all key value pairs of a dictionary and build all different values list for the same key using python.

Sample data:

```
"list": [
    {
      "1": 1
    }, 
    {
      "1": 8
    }, 
    {
      "1": 9
    },
    {
      "1": 1
    }, 
    {
      "2": 8
    }, 
    {
      "2": 10
    }
  ],
```

For the above list, I need to build a list like:

```
[{"1":[1,8,9]}, {"2":[8,10]}]
```

Comment: Alright, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Can you provide the full input list? We can't get the output based on what you have shown.

Comment: Why is your result a single element list and why does your input list contain single element dictionaries? This is not the right way to store data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want

```
import collections
input_ = {'list': [{'1': 1}, {'1': 8}, {'1': 9}, {'1': 1}, {'2': 8}, {'2': 10}]}
result = collections.defaultdict(list)

for elem in input_['list']:
    key, value = next(iter(elem.items()))  # best way to extract data from your strange format
    if value not in result[key]:
         result[key].append(value)

result = [dict(result)]  # put it in the strange format you want
```

outputs

```
[{'1': [1, 8, 9], '2': [8, 10]}]
```

However I strongly recommend reconsidering how you structure your data. For example, your input should be a list of tuples, not a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

this should do the trick - but please notice that doing a dictionary with only one key and value is not the way to save data.

```
new_dict = {}
for pair in your_list:
    for key in pair:
        if key in new_dict:
            new_dict[key] = new_dict[key].append(pair[key])
        else:
            new_dict[key] = [pair[key]]

print new_dict
```

new_dict is a dictionary with key -> list of values mapping

Comment: `pair[0]` will throw a `KeyError` since none of those dictionaries have a key `0`

Comment: where in his example do you see that?

Comment: `"list": [
    {
      "1": 1
    },  ...` hence `pair` is of type `dict`, not `tuple`. Try and run your code with OP's input.